# C code to MIPS code error

Tags: c, mips

I came across this problem that asks to convert from c to MIPS code.

```
B[8] = A[i-j];
```

where $s6 and $s7 stores the base address of array A and B. i and j are stored in $s3 and $s4.

This is my solution:

```
sub $t0,$s3,$s4 # i - j
sll $t0,$t0,2 # (i - j) * 4
add $t0,$s6,$t0 # A + (i - j) * 4
lw $t1,0($t0) # *(A + (i - j) * 4)
sw $t1,32($s7) # *(B + 32) = *(A + (i - j) * 4)
```

This is the solution given to us:

```
sub $t0, $s3, $s4
add $t0, $s6, $t0
lw $t1, 16($t0)
sw $t1, 32($s7)
```

The solution given to us doesn't make any sense to me as it certainly fails almost all cases as the address might not be word aligned. Does anyone think that the solution given to us is correct?

Comment: What are the types of `A` and `B`?

Comment: @interjay integer array

Comment: Then their solution doesn't seem correct. I don't see where the 16 comes from at all - makes it look like they're answering a different question.

Comment: @interjay That's what I thought too, 16 pop's up from nowhere. Just wanted to confirm that! Thanks!